# Activating cron restarts on pm2 after reboot

Tags: node.js, cron, pm2

Currently, I have this `ecosystem.config.js` file setup:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'Bot',
            script: `./src/index.js`,
            watch: false,
            autorestart: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'Post Stats',
            script: `./jobs/postStats.js`,
            cron_restart: '*/30 * * * *',
            watch: false,
            autorestart: false,
        },
    ],
}
```

I then run this with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` and everything works fine, with the various files restarting when expected.

To get the process to start automatically on system start up, I run `pm2 startup` and run the command suggested (as shown in https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/). I then run `pm2 save` to save the current config.

Then, when I restart the server, and the `Bot` process starts as expected but the `Post Stats` process doesn't.

How can I have the cron restart re-registered when the server restarts?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.   Any suggestions?

Comment: I ended up not using pm2 at all and just used a Linux cronjob instead. It probably required slightly more setup but is a cleaner solution overall imo

Comment: There's a github issue here open about this here https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5443
It looks like there's a PR open for it so maybe fixed soon(tm)